# programmatically close select onorientationchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iphone-standalone-web-app

I can't seem to close a select element when rotating an IOS device.

I've tried blur() (both native and jQuery versions), setting its style to display:none, calling hide(), triggering focus events on other elements, triggering click events on the on both the select and other elements, disabling the select, hiding all the options, etc. etc.

I know webkit doesn't let you close selects with blur().  Anybody have anymore suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean with "close"?

Comment: Essentially, blur the element and leave the selected option unchanged.

EDIT:  I guess the clearest way to say it is that I want to remove focus the element.

Comment: why would yo want to do that? normal user behavior is: "I can't read clearly the select options, so I change the orientation, and obviously I'm happy if nothing what I've selected before has changed". Maybe you need to give a hint on the purpose you want to achieve and update your question

Comment: You could target a  hidden `<a>` tag when you rotate

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here since I have no way to test it, but it seems if you put an anchor in your page like this:

`<a id="myanchor"></a>`

And add something like this to your Jquery:

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
  $('#myanchor').focus();
});
```

It should focus on the anchor and close the select... Maybe?

Comment: I will try this, but I have already tried focusing other elements without success.

Comment: @erfling then it probably wont work, I was just trying to help :/